# I cannot start graphical apps as root

Tags: gui, sudo, root, gksu

I used to be able to do so, but something as simple as this fails now:

```
gksudo gedit
```

and this also fails:

```
sudo gedit
```

I receive the error:

```
Cannot open display.
```

I haved checked this:

- .Xauthority and .ICEauthority have my user as owner and also read/write permissions
- As both files are binary, I cannot understand them and check if they are corrupted

Probably, I have some misconfiguration.
I have read this [before](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo) and many other guides before asking.

I'm using Ubuntu Precise 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this? If so, how?

Comment: Why was this closed? The linked answer is quite obviously for a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing `export DISPLAY=:0` before the command as a workaround.

Or, alternatively, use `DISPLAY=:0 gksudo gedit`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

the answers you are locking for are

- [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/164842/32413)
- and an alternative one [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/164846/32413)

Comment: Thanks Boris, I've discovered new tricks.  But in my case it doesn't work.  Muy user has permissions to sudo.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in a terminal:

```
su -
```

this will ask root password and give a root terminal session, this worked for me, I could run gedit without problems, for example.