# How can I run an application with a GUI as admin from a non-admin user session?

Tags: sudo, gksu, su

I defined 2 user accounts:

- one with admin privilege (with `sudo` right) => lets call it **`adminuser`**.
- a 2nd one without any privilege => lets call it **`normaluser`**
  and I configure the autologin on this 2nd user **`normaluser`**.

So when I open a **`normaluser`** session and want to run an application with admin privilege, 
I open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and:

```
su adminuser
sudo anyapplication ...
```

It works fine, without having to quit the **`normaluser`** session (no need to open a **`adminuser`** session).

---

But what should I do if the application needs to run with a GUI (Graphic User Interface) ?
I though about that:

```
su adminuser
gksu anyapplication ...
```

but I get

```
** (gksu:9122): WARNING **: the connexion is closed
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
(gksu:9122): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Comment: So the question is: why did you configure your system this way? Do you think it improves security? It is not :) Instead, you could've configured auto-login on your "admin" account so it won't ask you for password when you log in - it will still require a password when you perform administrative tasks.

Comment: @Sergey If **`normaluser`** is sometimes used by someone who shouldn't be able to run commands as `root`, then making **`normaluser`** a non-administrator **definitely improves security**. The perils of giving someone a user account but not letting them know their own password go far beyond Boris's situation in hassle and complexity. If you want a full explanation of why that is problematic, I suggest posting a new question, but 3 of the reasons are that a user should be able to lock and unlock the screen, log out and back in with a different session type, and decrypt `ecryptfs` data.

Comment: exactly, for me it makes no sense to use my family's PC letting everybody know the admin password to unlock screen. This **`normaluser`** and **`adminuser`** setting is the golden rule.

Comment: Fair enough, I just got an impression the OP was using the `normaluser` account for everyday work and `admin` account for performing administrative tasks, which does not really improve anything. On a multi-user machine this totally makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### PAM can take care of it

This works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 (edit: it works too on 18.04 LTS):

put the line:

```
session optional pam_xauth.so
```

somewhere in:

```
/etc/pam.d/su
```

and/or

```
/etc/pam.d/sudo
```

and then doing "su -" or "sudo su -" I can use graphical apps as root.

Comment: Confirming that this works on Kubuntu 16.04 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it works for me too on 18.04 ! it seems to be the [best alternative](https://askubuntu.com/a/462848/32413) to `sux` and `gksu` that are not available anymore.

Answer (score 34):

## Terminology

In this answer:

- **`normaluser`** is a normal user who is not an administrator and cannot run commands as `root` with `sudo`.
- **`admin`** is an administrator who can run commands as `root` with `sudo`. (Of course, any graphical commands [should use a graphical frontend like `gksu`/`gksudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo), and not `sudo` directly.)
- **`anyapplication`** is the name of the graphical application **`normaluser`** wants to run as `root`. **`normaluser`** knows **`admin`**'s password and has (presumably) been told s/he may use it for this purpose.

## The Problem

The cause of your problem, and the reason most of the other answers so far don't work (with the exception of [Marty Fried](https://askubuntu.com/users/39753/marty-fried)'s [excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/164846/22949)), is:

- `gksu` can be configured to use either `sudo` *or* `su` as its backend. The default behavior of `gksu` in Ubuntu is to act as a frontend for `sudo`, *not* for `su`. That is to say that, by default, `gksu` and `gksudo` behave *exactly the same*. See [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html).
- **`normaluser`** is not an administrator and thus cannot run commands as `root` with `sudo`. `sudo` prompts for the password of *the user running it*, not the password of *the user they want to become*. Not being able to use your password to perform actions as people who aren't you is *what it means to not be an administrator*.
- **`normaluser`**, provided it is not a Guest account,  **can** run commands as another user *with `su`*, putting in the *other user's password*. But `gksu` acts as a frontend for `sudo`, not `su`.
- **`normaluser`** cannot *directly* run any command as `root`, because **`normaluser`** cannot use **`sudo`**, and *nobody* can become `root` with `su` because [*there is no `root` password*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Background_Information).

## The Solution

The solution requires writing a command that performs two authentication steps:

- **`normaluser`** must become **`admin`** to run a graphical command. To do this, **`normaluser`** must run `gksu` with the `-w` flag to make it run in **su-mode** instead of the default **sudo-mode**, and the `-u` flag to run the command as **`admin`** instead of `root`.
- The command run as **`admin`** must invoke `gksu` *without* the `-w` flag to use `sudo` to become `root`.

**Here's the command** (yes, I have tested it **;-)**):

```
gksu -w -u admin gksu anyapplication
```

You will be prompted for a password *twice*:

1. First, you must enter **`admin`**'s password, to let **`normaluser`** run a command as **`admin`** with the `su` backend.
2. Second, you must enter **`admin`**'s password, to let **`admin`** run a command as **`root`** with the `sudo` backend.

That's right. You enter **`admin`**'s password twice.

Miscellaneous notes:

- If you wish, you can replace the second `gksu` with `gksudo` to make it less confusing. In Ubuntu, they are equivalent. (You can also replace the first `gksu` with `gksudo`, but that would be extremely counterintuitive and confusing.)
- `-w` is the short form of `--su-mode`.
- `-S` is the short form of `--sudo-mode` but neither has to be used because **sudo-mode** is the default.
- You may want to test this with some pretty harmless command first, to make sure it does what you want. (It will, but there's no need for you to trust me on that.) For example:

  ```
  gksu -w -u admin gksu xclock
  ```

  `xclock` is a nice simple clock-window application.

Comment: PERFECT, I add an alias in my .bashrc right away to avoid forgetting this clever tip

Comment: do not know why, but now (with ubuntu 14.04) I have to start with `sudo` to make it work. Example: `sudo gksu -w -u thedude gksu xclock`

Comment: FYI: `kdesudo` looks to work cleaner, at least on KUbuntu.

Comment: unfortunately, it seems that `gksu` is not available anymore

Answer (score 12):

One way that will probably work is to use "sux" rather than "su" when you first switch to the admin user.  sux fixes the problem of running x applications from the spoofed user.  It is in the standard repo, and can be installed by entering `sudo apt-get install sux` at a commandline.

Then, just use "sux" instead of "su" and it should work the way you expect.

Lets reuse the example of the application `xclock`:

```
sux admin
gksu xclock
```

Comment: There is no more version of `sux` on Ubuntu 14.04 64bits `;(`

Comment: Seems that there is [an alternative](http://askubuntu.com/a/462848/32413)

Comment: @Boris It's a shell script, you can just download it from a historic repo and put it into your path, for example from https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/sux

Answer (score 7):

### pkexec

There is an ubiquitous alternative to kdesudo and gksu - `pkexec` which is from `policykit-1` package that is required by lots of packages.

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer to explain how a regular user (who is not an administrator and cannot become root with `sudo` or polkit), who knows the password of an administrator (i.e., of someone who *can* become root with `sudo` or polkit), can use `pkexec` to run a graphical program as root. **That's what the question here is asking.** It's not clear to me that `pkexec` will do this, at least without extensively editing configuration files, especially since `pkexec` cannot generally be used to run arbitrary graphical programs (without polkit profiles) *at all*. Is there a way?

Comment: @EliahKagan This works on Ubuntu with default configuration - just run `pkexec command` and it works. The configuration is in the file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.policy` which is installed by the named package.  And it actually require you to write the admin password only once

Comment: if you got an error "cannot open display" then try to pass DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY env variables e.g.  `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY nautilus`

Answer (score 2):

For me worked this:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY yourcommand commandoption1 commandoption2
```

Here you have to replace the `yourcommand commandoption1 commandoption2` part with real command and it's args

Comment: This would actually work! All the other gksu etc. will not work since no major distros ship these tools.

Answer (score 2):

In Lubuntu, there's a tool called `lxqt-sudo`. It's in the official repositories.
It works!

`lxqt-sudo/groovy`, now `0.15.0-0ubuntu1 amd64`, is a Graphical Qt frontend for plain `sudo`.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lxqt-sudo

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sudo` with GUI using the options `-sE`, as follows:

`sudo -sE GUI_CMD`

For example, if you want to run `nemo` as root:

`sudo -sE nemo`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
su admin
gksu anyapplication ...
```

I suggest you to try `gksu -u admin anyapplication`, where you do everything using the `gksu` command itself.
Also please make note that you have to enter the password of the user mentioned in the command, ie, in this case you have to enter **admin**'s password.

Comment: On a default-configured Ubuntu system, if `normaluser` runs `gksu -u admin anyapplication` it will prompt for  `normaluser`'s password to become `admin` using the `sudo` backend, just as `gksu anyapplication` would prompt for `normaluser`'s password to become `root` using the `sudo` backend. Both will fail for the same reason--`normaluser` does not have the power to run commands with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically use the following logic in my scripts so that they will always request privilege escalation themselves using the appropriate method:

```bsh
load_function_library

if [[ ${UID} -eq 0 ]] ; then
    # Execute only in the case of elevated privileges:
    if hash dialog ; then
        if ( dialog --backtitle "$( basename $0 )" --title "${BRAND} tools updater: NOTICE!" --yesno "\nMay I update the ${BRAND} OEM tools on your system now?" 20 80 ) ; then
            clear && do_update
        else
            clear && exit
        fi
    else
        echo -e $YELLOW
        echo "Hello $SUDO_USER ... I am going to update the OEM tools now..."
        echo "To cancel this, just close the terminal or press "CRTL C"."
        echo " "
        read -p "Press [ ENTER ] to continue with update"
        echo -e $ENDCOLOR
        do_update
    fi
else
    # If privileges are not elevated; then request elevation using the appropriate method:
    if echo $(systemctl get-default ) |grep graphical ; then pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY $0 ; else ensure_admin ; fi
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
gksudo AppName
```

This brings up a graphical password request first (your user's password), and then starts the GUI-app as root (I just tried, it really does. Funny thing: I tried `gksu AppName` immediately thereafter, and that worked as well -- as it is probably supposed to, as the "gk" prefix suggests. So I'm not completely sure where your problem may be located).

Comment: it works in your case because you have tried from an admin user session with sudo right. What about from a non admin user session without sudo right?

Comment: i used gksudo from a normal terminal window with a non-admin user (my own user). You are correct however for the second try, as I still had sudo perms then. But the problem of Boris is a different one: his app cannot connect to X, which in my case worked both times. As you can see from the original question, `sudo` in text mode is working for him.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one super user and that is root.

User 1 is an admin and has sudo rights.
User 2 is not an admin and does not have sudo rights.

Try logging in as user 1 then using the command

```
gksudo app-name
```

(replacing app-name with the app name)
Hope that helps - let me know. :o)

EDIT : More info as requested

If it is just you on the computer,
then using user 1 (who has permission to use sudo)
is no different to using user 2 (who does not have permission to use sudo).
User 1 has the same rights as user 2.
Unless user 1 issues a command prefixed with sudo and / or provides their password to allow applications to run with root privelages.
The only difference is that user 2 cannot run apps as root.

Hope that helps explain it a bit for you. :o)

Comment: thanks for the clarification between super user and admin, I will edit my question. What do you mean by "logging as user 1" => open the session with user 1 ? well that is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: added more info to answer as requested :o)

Comment: well my wife and my kids are using the user2 with the autologin, so I rather like not having sudo right with that user.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea - I have kids too ;o). Did you try logging in as user1 yet and and running the command?

Comment: Yes I can but it is painful to change user session. I usually have to do it several times: go on admin session to define some settings, switch to normal user session to test, and again and again, it is very nice to be able to do that staying on the normal session. Most of the time I handle it with `su admin` + `sudo ...` example `sudo vi file`, except for application with GUI

Answer (score -2):

Here's the command to accomplish this.

```
gksu app-name
```

Run it **without** running `su` first. You only need to run the above command from a normal user session and the application will be run as root.

Comment: it does not work - note that I m trying from a user session with no privilege

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: entering my `normal` user password - I get the message "Impossible to launch as root user"

Comment: entering my `superuser/admin` password - I get the message "incorrect password, try again"