# How do I gain access of my files again?

Tags: upgrade, users, session, user-profile

Hello,
I know I shouldn't have, but I've interrupted the upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 14.10 and now I can't go past the login screen... When I try to launch Ubuntu in recovery mode, it displays an error message and I can't even connect to the internet. I've looked for solutions but found none and don't really want to burn a better installation cd.
The **real** problem is that I can't access my session! I installed ubuntu on another partition and tried to copy all of my documents onto a usb drive but since I'm on another session, **I am not the owner of my files!**
The title says it all; please help! I really need my files back!

Comment: The title does not say it all. _What_ error message? So what if you're not the owner of your files? That shouldn't stop you copying them. You can always use `sudo cp`. How exactly did you try to copy and how did it fail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recovering user files with a Live CD](http://askubuntu.com/q/78691/22949) or [How to access and copy files from an old/other Ubuntu system's partition?](http://askubuntu.com/q/240030/22949)

Answer (score 1):

You can open a terminal and run `sudo nautilus`.

You should gain access to your files.

Comment: I can see them and read them (eg. music files) but I have no read/write permissions!

Comment: @Quertie if you can see/read them, you have read permissions. To copy them, that's all you need as long as you have write permissions to the destination directory.

Comment: @ToDo `gksudo nautilus` (or `sudo -H nautilus` or `sudo -i nautilus`, if you don't have the `gksu` package installed that provides the `gksudo` command) is preferable to `sudo nautilus`, since running graphical applications with `sudo` [sometimes creates annoying application configuration problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application).

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo chown -R /path/to/my/folder $USER:$USER
```

This will change the owner of the directory to give you access again.