# How do I copy files and change directory read/write permissions using the GUI?

Tags: gui, copy

There's a GUI for copying files and changing permissions, so I'd like to use it. How can I change directory read/write permissions in the GUI and use the GUI's 'Copy to' function? Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: Related but *not* a dupe: [How to access and copy files from an old/other Ubuntu system's partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/240030), [Recovering user files with a Live CD](https://askubuntu.com/q/78691) Note that those answers should *maybe* be updated, but it's not obvious how or even *that* they should. Newer Ubuntu systems don't ship with the `gksu` or `gksudo`, but several official derivatives still have them. *`sudo -H` remains available.* The main issue is how running GUI programs as root is increasingly unpopular and requires extra effort on new Ubuntu systems that default to Wayland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy files within the GUI using the Nautilus file manager (now called "Files") built into Ubuntu.

As far as using a GUI to change file permissions the only program I've found is called [Eiciel](https://rofi.roger-ferrer.org/eiciel/). I've never used the program and can not vouch for it.

Here's a screenshot from the Developer's page:

[image: Eiciel screen shot]