# 'indicator-cpu' won't start, what is wrong?

Tags: 12.04

Working with 12.04 desktop version although GUI is disabled. When I try to launch indicator-cpufreq I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could n
ot open display

warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)

** (indicator-cpufreq:4955): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=
13d2f8aab40f0bc001c139be00000007 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non
-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:54: GtkWarning:
IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  appindicator.CATEGORY_HARDWARE)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:54: Warning: inv
alid (NULL) pointer instance
  appindicator.CATEGORY_HARDWARE)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:54: Warning: g_s
ignal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  appindicator.CATEGORY_HARDWARE)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:61: Warning: inv
alid (NULL) pointer instance
  menu = gtk.Menu()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:61: Warning: g_s
ignal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  menu = gtk.Menu()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:73: GtkWarning:
IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  menu_item = gtk.RadioMenuItem(group, readable_frequency(freq))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:73: Warning: g_o
bject_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  menu_item = gtk.RadioMenuItem(group, readable_frequency(freq))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:87: GtkWarning:
IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  menu_item = gtk.RadioMenuItem(group, readable_governor(governor))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:87: Warning: g_o
bject_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  menu_item = gtk.RadioMenuItem(group, readable_governor(governor))

(indicator-cpufreq:4955): libappindicator-WARNING **: Unable to get the session
bus: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=13d2f8aab40f0bc001c139be00000007 --b
inary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch erro
r: X11 initialization failed.\n

(indicator-cpufreq:4955): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus
: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=13d2f8aab40f0bc001c139be00000007 --bina
ry-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error:
X11 initialization failed.\n
/usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq:82: GtkWarning: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you mus
t always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
  gtk.main()
/usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq:82: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_display: assertion
 `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  gtk.main()
/usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq:82: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_keymap_get_for_display: asser
tion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
  gtk.main()
/usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq:82: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  gtk.main()
/usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq:82: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE
_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  gtk.main()
```

My question is simply, what does this mean? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/164819/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-a-gui-as-super-user-from-a-normal-user-session or

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the developer launchpad and post this there. You will get a more accurate and quickly response:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq