# How can I load gui applications under an su session?

Tags: graphics, evince, su

When I log into gnome in Ubuntu 12.04, I can type the following on the command line to open a pdf:

```
evince mypdf.pdf
```

However, the following does not work.

```
su 
evince mypdf.pdf
```

That gives the following error:

```
(evince:1368): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported


               ** (evince:1368): WARNING **: The connection is closed
                                 No protocol specified
                                 No protocol specified
                                 Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

How can I fix it so that changing users on the command line does not break GUI applications?

Comment: Have you checked out [this related Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164819/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-a-gui-as-super-user-from-a-normal-user-session?rq=1)?

Comment: Search for it, but did not find it. Looking at it now.

Comment: The answers to that question are not quite what I am looking for because, they only allow one to run an application as root. 
I would like to be able to run application as another (network) user.

Comment: Also, in the root case, is there a way to su to a root shell and run applications without prepending everything with gksu?

Comment: I am sorry, but I won't be able to help you. I really don't know too much about account management. I would advise you to update your post with these new questions and details. That way your post will be bumped and other user will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you use gksu

```
gksu evince mypdf.pdf
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo