# Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory

Tags: sudo, gui, users, user-management, mir

After logging in as another user how do I run GUI programs?

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo -u hawat -i
hawat@doge:~$ 
hawat@doge:~$ whoami
hawat
hawat@doge:~$ 
hawat@doge:~$ pwd
/home/hawat
hawat@doge:~$ 
hawat@doge:~$ echo $HOME
/home/hawat
hawat@doge:~$ 
hawat@doge:~$ firefox
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
hawat@doge:~$
```

Answer (score 14):

`export DISPLAY=:0` worked for me. Make sure you execute the command on the connecting system, not on the system you're connecting to!

Comment: On the machine I was using to connect, not the machine you are connecting to.

Comment: ahhh, this is on the same box.  diff accounts.

Comment: Did not have any effect on my computer

Comment: not work for me. I don't know why this is happening to me.

Answer (score 6):

**This answer works on my Ubuntu 16.04 and Mir** (with slight adaptations):

[**Run x command as another user using xauth**](https://serverfault.com/questions/51005/how-to-use-xauth-to-run-graphical-application-via-other-user-on-linux#answer-51581)

### Wrapper bash script:

For convenience, [I created a wrapper bash script](https://gist.github.com/lentschi/605b031ea32d7c5c0655b5008ed8ee2a), that you might want to download to `/usr/local/bin/xsudo` and mark executable (`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xsudo`).

Then simply run:

```
xsudo hawat firefox
```

### Potential Alternatives:

- As a far simpler alternative, you might look into `pam_xauth` (s. [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428284/what-is-a-good-alternative-to-the-sux-command#answer-462848)) However this doesn't work for me for some reason. (I still get the error about firefox not being able to connect to the display at :0)
- In a lot of forums you might see the command `xhost +local:` or similar, which *will* make `gksudo -u hawat firefox` work without any wrapper script. **However** be aware that this opens a **security loophole**: Any active user on your local host will be able to access your keyboard, mouse, screen etc.
- There used to be [sux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/suxterm.1.html), which has been discontinued for some reason - you might still be able to download and use it though. As far as I can tell, it did something similar to my script only a lot more. Unfortunately I couldn't find out, why this is no longer maintained. (Maybe because we should now use pam_xauth instead - s. first alternative)

Answer (score 3):

After spending way too much time on this, I discovered that with Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04, the correct value is `DISPLAY=:1`, not `DISPLAY=:0` as it has been from time immemorial.

Answer (score 1):

**export DISPLAY=:0** works fine but this is a temporary solution since you need to type this each time when you open the terminal.

**Permanent Solution :**
The problem might be due to env_keep variable in /etc/sudoers. Add the following line at the end of /etc/sudoers using gedit or using **sudo visudo**

> Defaults env_keep+="DISPLAY"

**Note :**
Keep in mind to always use **"+="** while adding to env_keep. In case if there are any other env_keep with **"="** change them to **"+="** because using **"="** will override other values.

Comment: FYI: keep in mind you aren't supposed to edit the sudoers file directly, but by using the `visudo` wrapper, which provides some sanity checking before writing a new sudoers file.