# Why can I not use gksudo/sudo with any GUI program?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, sudo, gui, gksudo

In my Ubuntu 12.04.2 with GNOME-Shell I'm not able anymore to run any graphical programs with `gksudo` or `sudo`.

I always get an error like `cannot open display`

I don't remember any particular changes I've done manually apart of the regular updates. 
I use also [GNOME3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) and [Q-series LTS Backport PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/q-lts-backport).

I noticed also that I'm not able anymore to install extensions from the website, but I think it's not related, of course I'm not sure too :)

I've already spent time and effort searching the topic everywhere and the few I found didn't give any solution for me. I don't want to  reinstall.

Comment: This question has been asked before with some answers (but none accepted): http://askubuntu.com/questions/163384/i-cannot-start-graphical-apps-as-root

Comment: Thanks, already checked that's why I'm asking again. Anyway all the xorg packages was reinstalled under the _xserver-xorg-renamed_ package so now every xorg package name end with a _-lts-quantal_ . Of course I can't going back to the previous packages.

Answer (score 0):

What does:

> not able anymore to run any graphical programs with gksudo or sudo

mean?

If you see:

> *username* is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported

While trying to "sudo" smth, instructions from **[psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo)** might be helpful to you.

Generally, you need to have root shell to check and, if necessary, modify `/etc/sudoers` file. You should also be in *admin* group:

`usermod -a -G admin username` #from the root shell

Comment: thanks amdenis. simply the terminal says "cannot open display", and even absolutely nothing if for example I use **gksudo** to open nautilus.  _/etc/sudoers/_  is ok, and **sudo** in terminal is working perfectly. I mean **sudo nano** is working, **sudo gedit** is not working, **gedit** is working